# scaling a discord bot to potentially 100k plus concurrent users

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So currently I'm struggling to find an efficient way to scale a discord bot written in node.It currently has music capabilities and over 100 chat commands plus moderation features. I'm in talks with large scale partnered discord servers to put my bot on their server but don't have a clue how id scale to that number and beyond.

Any Help would be appreciated <3 (also my 1st post so pls be gentle lol)